# r how many OR items support grepl?

Tags: r, grepl

I need to build a search into a string variable with grepl. The thing is I have many patterns to search, and the patterns may grow in time. So the question is:
How many patterns can I put in a single grepl sentence?
Actually, I´m using a separate csv file where I store the patterns, each in a row as follows:

```
#lee la lista de valores de la categoria
cat.Super<-read.csv("./data/diccionario.csv", header = FALSE, 
                    sep = ",",encoding="UTF-8")

#transpone el archivo para la busqueda
tSuper.0<-as.list(t(cat.Super))

#arma el patron de busqueda
tSuper.1<-do.call("paste", c(tSuper.0, sep = "|"))

#busca en la variable desciption y crea una variable T/F en el data frame
datos.1$super.0<-grepl(tSuper.1,datos.1$description)
```

Thanks in advance
Oscar

Comment: The number of patterns will certainly depend on their lengths. I found that in `gsub` maximum length of a pattern divided by `|` is 1463 symbols.